# Replace text between two points in string

Tags: php, html, regex

This may seem like a no-brainier, but the thing is I wont know the length of the string in advance. My client has a pre-made/bought Blog which adds youtube videos into posts via its CMS - basically I want my function to search a string like the following:

```
<embed width="425" height="344" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"     pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/somevid"></embed>
```

and regardless of the current width and height values, I want to replace them with my own constants e.g width="325" height="244". Could someone kindly explain the best way to go about this?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes, DOMDocument can help you here, find the tag, replace the attributes and save the whole page.

Comment: Not wordpress, just some generic blog software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMDocument` FTW!

```
<?php

define("EMBED_WIDTH", 352);
define("EMBED_HEIGHT", 244);

$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<embed width="425" height="344" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/somevid"></embed>


</body>
</html>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);

$embeds = $document->getElementsByTagName("embed");

$pattern = <<<REGEXP
|
(https?:\/\/)?   # May contain http:// or https://
(www\.)?         # May contain www.
youtube\.com     # Must contain youtube.com
|xis
REGEXP;

foreach ($embeds as $embed) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $embed->getAttribute("src"))) {
        $embed->setAttribute("width", EMBED_WIDTH);
        $embed->setAttribute("height", EMBED_HEIGHT);
    }
}

echo $document->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use regex expressions to replace it. For instance:

```
    if(preg_match('#<embed .*type="application/x-shockwave-flash".+</embed>#Us', $originalString)) {
        $string = preg_replace('#width="\d+"#', MY_WIDTH_CONSTANT, $originalString);
    }
```

The ".*" means any character. Like we pass the "s" flag after the sharp, we also accept line breaks. The "U" flag means *ungreedy*. It will stop at the first closing embed tag found.

The "\d+" means one or more digits.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.